# Using Umbraco.TinyMCE and Umbraco.MediaPicker3 in a custom form

Tags: tinymce, umbraco

I have a requirement to allow members (with no back office access) to post blog entries in an Umbraco 11 site.

I have created a custom form to do this following [this example](https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/fundamentals/code/creating-forms). It works fine when using a simple Text Area as the main content editor. However, I would like to use the Umbraco.TinyMCE editor in its place.

Similarly, I would like to use the Umbraco.MediaPicker3 editor to allow the member to select an image for the post.

How do I do that?